# Fontawesome doesn't scale up

Tags: pdftex, fontsize, fontawesome

**Edit:** @cfr said, that in the new version 4.4.0 the bug was fixed.

I have written a small sample to test, if the [fontawesome script](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome) (v. 4.3.0-1) scales up with the font size which I want, but it doesn't :(

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

{Normal \faAdjust}
{\Huge Huge \faAdjust}

\end{document}
```

I have rendered the tex file with pdflatex.

[image: rendered tex]

Do I miss something?

Comment: Welcome! Is XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX an option? Because it works fine with those.

Comment: Well, I had have many renderer problems, with both of them in my TeXnicCenter / MiKTeX setup. So I looked for a way with pdflatex ;)

Comment: I recommend reporting this as a bug to the package author. The package ought not define the fonts for LaTeX this way. It is just wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The author of the sty didn't wrote the code so that the font scales. You can adapt it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{fontawesomeOne}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{fontawesomeOne}{m}{n}
  {<-> FontAwesome--fontawesomeone}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand\FAone{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{fontawesomeOne}\selectfont} 
\begin{document}

{Normal \faAdjust}
{\Huge Huge \faAdjust}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You will have to write similar definitions for `\FAtwo` and `\FAthree`.

Comment: (+1) If you object to my posting my answer, let me know and I'll happily delete it. You posted while I was writing and mine took a bit longer, perhaps. (I am also probably slower.) I would usually use `\DeclareRobustCommand` here rather than `\renewcommand` but I am not entirely sure whether I need to do so or not. Is it just unnecessary in general or unnecessary here? Or is there some positive reason to avoid it?

Comment: @cfr I never delete answers (unless they are really wrong) and I don't expect other to do it. We are not at a race here. The world is large enough for all of us and for more than one answer with similar content. And you are right about the `\DeclareRobustCommand`. It was a bit late yesterday.

Answer (score 10):

The `fontawesome.sty` file does a very wrong thing. At its end you find

```
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                pdflatex implementation
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\else
% definition of \FA... as a shortcut to load the Font Awesome font
\pdfmapline{+FontAwesome--fontawesomeone FontAwesome "fontawesomeone ReEncodeFont" <[fontawesomeone.enc <FontAwesome.pfb}
\font\FAone=FontAwesome--fontawesomeone.enc
\pdfmapline{+FontAwesome--fontawesometwo FontAwesome "fontawesometwo ReEncodeFont" <[fontawesometwo.enc <FontAwesome.pfb}
\font\FAtwo=FontAwesome--fontawesometwo.enc
\pdfmapline{+FontAwesome--fontawesomethree FontAwesome "fontawesomethree ReEncodeFont" <[fontawesomethree.enc <FontAwesome.pfb}
\font\FAthree=FontAwesome--fontawesomethree.enc

% icon-specific commands
\input{fontawesomesymbols-pdftex.tex}

\fi
```

and it's well known that using `\font` in LaTeX is always wrong.

You can fix it by properly defining `\FAone`, `\FAtwo` and `\FAthree` to do the right thing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{fontawesome1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{fontawesome1}{m}{n}{<->FontAwesome--fontawesomeone}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{fontawesome2}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{fontawesome2}{m}{n}{<->FontAwesome--fontawesometwo}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{fontawesome3}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{fontawesome3}{m}{n}{<->FontAwesome--fontawesomethree}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\FAone}{\usefont{U}{fontawesome1}{m}{n}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\FAtwo}{\usefont{U}{fontawesome2}{m}{n}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\FAthree}{\usefont{U}{fontawesome3}{m}{n}}

\begin{document}

{Normal \faAdjust}
{\Huge Huge \faAdjust}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The correct code in the package should be

```
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                pdflatex implementation
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\else
% definition of \FA... as a shortcut to load the Font Awesome font
\pdfmapline{+FontAwesome--fontawesomeone FontAwesome "fontawesomeone ReEncodeFont" <[fontawesomeone.enc <FontAwesome.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+FontAwesome--fontawesometwo FontAwesome "fontawesometwo ReEncodeFont" <[fontawesometwo.enc <FontAwesome.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+FontAwesome--fontawesomethree FontAwesome "fontawesomethree ReEncodeFont" <[fontawesomethree.enc <FontAwesome.pfb}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{fontawesome1}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{fontawesome1}{m}{n}{<->FontAwesome--fontawesomeone}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{fontawesome2}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{fontawesome2}{m}{n}{<->FontAwesome--fontawesometwo}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{fontawesome3}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{fontawesome3}{m}{n}{<->FontAwesome--fontawesomethree}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\FAone}{\usefont{U}{fontawesome1}{m}{n}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\FAtwo}{\usefont{U}{fontawesome2}{m}{n}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\FAthree}{\usefont{U}{fontawesome3}{m}{n}}

% icon-specific commands
\input{fontawesomesymbols-pdftex.tex}

\fi
```

Comment: I hadn't seen it yesterday - it was a bit late - but now I wonder what the `.enc` is doing at the end of the fontname and why it works if one uses it (it works without it too, the font name in the pdfmapline command in the sty doesn't have it, and the tfm doesn't have the `.enc` in its name. ). Looks as if latex is removing the .enc silently.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I trusted the package author. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg - I notified the package author a week ago or so about this (incl. some suggestions to rectify it).  The package should provide a separate `fontawesome.map` and some `ufontawesome[one|two|three].fd`.  After that, the font can also be used with LaTeX/dvips and it goes the standard LaTeX way.  The package respositoy is [here](https://github.com/xdanaux/fontawesome-latex).

Comment: @ArashEsbati It would be surely a good thing.

Answer (score 6):

The package author has corrected the package to provide an appropriate configuration for LaTeX and the package now supports scaling with (pdf)TeX. With the current CTAN version (v4.4.0), which is also now in TeX Live, the OP's MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}

{Normal \faAdjust}
{\Huge Huge \faAdjust}

\end{document}
```

produces the expected output:

[image: expected output]

Hence, if you have an updated copy of the package installed, the manual corrections discussed in the other answers here are no longer necessary ;).

Answer (score 4):

As [Ulrike Fischer said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257579/), the package does not set the fonts up correctly for pdfLaTeX. As a result, they cannot be scaled using the ordinary font sizing commands. This is specific to the use of pdfLaTeX and does not affect XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX.

Ulrike Fischer posted her answer while I was writing mine. Since mine includes a more complete configuration, I hope that she will not mind my posting it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FontAwesomeOne}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FontAwesomeOne}{m}{n}{<-> FontAwesome--fontawesomeone}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand\FAone{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{FontAwesomeOne}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FontAwesomeTwo}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FontAwesomeTwo}{m}{n}{<-> FontAwesome--fontawesometwo}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand\FAtwo{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{FontAwesomeTwo}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FontAwesomeThree}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FontAwesomeThree}{m}{n}{<-> FontAwesome--fontawesomethree}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand\FAthree{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{FontAwesomeThree}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

{Normal \faAdjust}
{\Huge Huge \faAdjust}

\end{document}
```

[image: demonstration]

It is also worth noting that there is no reason - besides the package author's decisions - that the fonts cannot be used with the regular TeX engine as well. However, as it is there is limited support for pdfLaTeX and none at all for LaTeX, so far as I can tell.

Comment: There's no need at all to define all shape/series combinations.

Comment: @egreg I prefer to define them and not get spurious warnings about missing fonts. I agree that it is not necessary in the sense that it will work without. But it clutters the console output and the log file with warnings I don't need to worry about which makes it harder to find the ones I should pay attention to.

Comment: I get no missing font warning with my code.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! You are right that in this case there is no reason not to stipulate the shape and series in the definition of the font command. In general, I specify additions because often there *is* a reason not to stipulate them in the definition of font commands, but I still prefer to avoid spurious console warnings. I've updated my answer. (Don't tell me I could use `\usefont`. I know but I don't like it. It makes it harder for me to understand what my code is doing. Harder for me, that is. I am not claiming it is a bad command in general.)

Comment: Look at line 2338 of `latex.ltx`. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I know. I just find it harder *to read*. I'm not denying it does the same thing.