# fontawesome and pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, fontspec, fontawesome

When using pdflatex and the fontawesome package the below error shows up.

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

Wish to keep on using "pdflatex" instead of "xelatex" or "lualatex".

In fontawesome Version 4.4.0 manual it says "When using the (pdf)(LA)TEX
engine, the fontawesome package doesn’t require any external package".

Tried solutions proposed for this question ([Fontawesome doesn't scale up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257574/fontawesome-doesnt-scale-up)) without success.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
{\faAdjust}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From `fontawesome` manual (abstract) `This package requires the fontspec package and either the X Ǝ (L
A )T E X or
Lua(L
A )T E X engine to load the included otf font.`  Hence it won't work with `pdflatex`.

Comment: It also says "When using the (pdf)(LA)TEX engine, the fontawesome package doesn’t require any external package".

Comment: @HarishKumar. Not true. Recent versions work with pdflatex: "This pack­age works both with Xe(LA)TEX and Lua(LA)TEX (us­ing fontspec to load the in­cluded orig­i­nal otf font), as well as pdf(LA)TEX (us­ing an in­cluded type1 con­ver­sion and char­ac­ter map­ping of the font)."

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Then my version is old. :(

Comment: Anyone can reproduce the error?

Comment: @Tex Learner: Simply your fontawesome is old. If you update it, fontspec is not
loaded in your case.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto I have made sure that the package is ver 4.4. and I even reinstalled MiKTex... still have this error msg.

Comment: @Tex Learner: Then your installation may be wrong, or you are not using
the newly installed one. It is inconsistent with the manual:
The fontawesome package requires the fontspec package when using the X.(LA)TEX
or Lua(LA)TEX engines to load the included otf font. When using the (pdf)(LA)TEX
engine, the fontawesome package doesn't require any external package.

MiKTeX? It seems that
`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty`
shows that you are using TeX Live on some Unix system.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Thanks for the suggestion. I'm using MiKTeX but I made a mistake in question such that "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty"  was not part of the error msg. I copied this from other questions without noticing this difference.  "cannot-use-pdftex" part was true.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Thanks to your comment, I now found where the problem is and will post answer to my own question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to a stray version of fontawesome.sty in the OP's system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @AkiraKakuto, the problem was that MikTex was still using old versions of the `fontawesome` package from the AppData/Roaming folder despite the package was updated using the package manager and the "update app" within MiKTex.

The problem is solved by deleting the `fontawesome` folder within AppData/Roaming/MiKTex/'version'.